# Looking for a splashback pattern in kitchen using 3 or 4 different square tile colours

Tags: kitchens, tile, design

I'm adding some ceramic tiles to a splashback in my kitchen, I'm using square ceramic tiles. I don't want to use just one colour, and using two only really offers me a chequerboard pattern so I was thinking of adding a third or even fourth colour (the tiles are quite muted earthy colours).

I'm looking for existing templates for a 3 or 4 colour design so I can calculate how many tiles of each colour I need, but I can't find any resources to help me with this. I expect to repeat the pattern but to give you an idea I have about 8m in length of splashback and expect it to be either 3 or 4 tiles high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right or wrong way to do it.  Experiment with whatever you have on hand:  dice, marbles, squares of paper, etc.  Hint:  even if you make mistakes, just finish it so it looks like it is *supposed* to be that way.

Here is a sampling of some ideas to get you started (from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=square%20tile%20patterns&safe=off&biw=1760&bih=988&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=QmuzVImLLoe3oQSj94L4Aw&sqi=2&ved=0CDwQsAQ#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=3%20color%20square%20tile%20patterns)).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]